# Not clear why init methods gets called on some class

Tags: ios, objective-c

again I am reading a book and there is such implementation of class:

```
@implementation BNRItemStore


// Init method
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        allItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;

}

#pragma mark singleton stuff

// Implementing singleton functionality
+(BNRItemStore*) sharedStore
{
    static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;

    // Check if instance of this class has already been created via sharedStore
    if(!sharedStore)
    {
        // No, create one
        sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
    }

    return sharedStore;

}

// This method gets called by alloc
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [self sharedStore];
}

#pragma mark Methods

// return pointer to allItems
-(NSArray*) allItems
{
    return allItems;
}

// Create a random item and add it to the array. Also return it.
-(BNRItem*) createItem
{
    BNRItem *p = [BNRItem randomItem];
    [allItems addObject:p];
    return p;
}

@end
```

The thing I find strange is that **Nowhere** outside the class, e.g., some other class, is the `init` method of `BNRItemStore` called. However, still by some means it gets called, even when someone has typed such code outside the `BNRItemStore` class:

```
    [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] createItem]; // This still calls the init method of BNRItemStore. How?
```

Can someone please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

```
sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
```

This line is responsible for the `init` call. First time entering `sharedStore` the `sharedStore` variable is `nil`, so the condition check fails and an instance of the class is initialized.

Comment: Hi Alexander, that was not my question, I know the program  enters the if clause because sharedStore is nil. The question is that apparently by calling `init` on `[super allocWithZone:nil]` calls `init` of the `BNRItemStore` class, eventhough `super allocWithZone` was used... do you get my point?

Answer (score 0):

`-init` gets called because `+sharedStore` calls it:

```
sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
```

`[super allocWithZone:nil]` skips the current class' implementation of allocWithZone and calls the superclass implementation. However, init is an ordinary method call so it doesn't skip the superclass implementation.

Although the quoted line makes it look like super is an object that you're sending a message to, it really means something like "self, but skip the current class' implementation and use the superclass instead". It doesn't affect messages sent to the returned object.